# Could A Torus World Have Rings?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, planets, astronomy, planetary-rings

Towards the end of this article (https://io9.gizmodo.com/what-would-the-earth-be-like-if-it-was-the-shape-of-a-d-1515700296) there is mention of the different kinds of orbits the moon of a Torus world could have.

Many of the more wild and crazy orbits would result in the moon becoming unstable and crashing into the planet. However, I'm interested in another possibility.

Could a Torus world have a system of planetary Rings?

Edit: To elaborate, would any of the more unconventional orbits mentioned in the article (particularity ones that process into a rosette) form a distinct set of rings, or would it end up as an indistinct cloud of dust?

Comment: I'm not sure but my guess is that any planetary ring would be subject to the same instabilities and complications as a moon would. So if that article is correct about the lunar orbits then you should be able to substitute in a ring in some cases. Except the figure 8 as I imagine the friction and collisions would cause far too many problems to keep it stable. If it's far enough out it should work.

Comment: That article is a must read for anyone interested in world building with non spherical worlds!

Comment: Another URL for Torus Earth is Anders Sandberg's webpage http://www.aleph.se/andart/archives/2014/02/torusearth.html Once there it's easy to find many other interesting concepts devised by Sandberg.

Comment: @a4android that's actually the same guy that wrote my linked article. But thanks for linking to more of his work!

Comment: @Lot-Of-Malarkey Your link at io9.com simply copied Sandberg's article in its entirety. I knew it was the same author. In fact, it was to provide access to more of his work that I added the link to the source material. Have fun with there!

Comment: @Virusbomb: There is one major difference between an orbiting satellite and a surrounding ring: the location of the center of mass. A moon's center of mass is inside of the moon. A ring's center of mass would be situated _inside the planet it orbits_. This should create a much more stable system. The moon needs to have a precise orbital speed to stay in the same trajectory, but a ring would not really be subject to such a finicky trajectory (its center of mass would be stationary, even if it rotates around its own axis/axes)

Comment: @Virusbomb: That doesn't mean the whole system could exist (there are other possible issues due to it being a toroidal planet); but when comparing moons versus planetary rings in general, I would expect the rings to be generally more stable in regards to staying in orbit and not crashing into the planet.

Answer (score 2):

Sure it could, but neither is a stable object, ring systems are never stable over geological time anyway but a torus planet is really not stable, at any habitable size it collapses into a sphere as soon as it sheds even a tiny amount of rotational momentum, which it will with a ring system or moon to fuel the orbit of said objects. Unless the whole set-up is artificial, in which case it can have whatever you like.